# Using messaging and rest to communicate services at the same time

Tags: architecture, microservices, node.js, apache-kafka

I have two microservices, USERS and PRODUCTS, the second one creates objects referred to first one so it needs first to check that exists

First I though in a redis cache, but then I realize that for other cases I'll need to communicate with kafka, for example for payment microservices where requires fire and forget. The problem is that I don't know how to expose services to both, rest api and kafka. I can run kafka consumer in background but I thought is better to have two microservices one handle the rest request and another the kafka to update the local cache. Its a valid approach? Should I go only with one method, kafka messaging and make a rest api to convert rest request into kafka messages? I show you and example, thanks in advance:[image: schema of architecture]

Comment: Wouldn’t it be way simpler if the product service listens to the user events itself?

Comment: So basically instead of kafka, have some infrastructure that supports pubsub such as RabbitMQ

Comment: yes would be simpler, but how? running kafka consumer in async at the same time that express? That add cpu consume, and if I need to scale the instances of product service, add more useless consume thought I dont know if is the most clean way to do it

Comment: Kafka is just a tool. If the tool doesn’t do what you need, pick another tool.